# Unable to create project in Eclipse using Lightning HostName

Tags: lightning, eclipse, force.com-ide

[image]I am trying to connect to sandbox from Eclipse. My org settings wont allow me to connect to sandbox using test.salesforce.com. I have to put hostname to create a project. As we know we have different host names for classic and Lightning. My problem is when I am trying to create project using Lightning HostName, I am getting below exception. I am able to create project with Classic view HostName.

I dont know if this is right question to ask or not. Just wanted to know if there is any possibility to create Force.com project with Lightning HostName.

Answer (score 0):

You are interpreting this **wrong**. **HostName** here does not signify the *domain* (as visual force domain or lightning domain), rather it signifies the **specific server instance**, excerpt below from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ProjectOrganizationPage.htm). And the instance URL irrespective of Classic vs. Lightning, **always remains the same**.

> This field is only available if you have chosen Other (Specify), in the Environment field above. Enter a **specific server instance**.

Irrespective of whether you are creating a Force.com project for Lightning or Visualforce page, a Project is a bundle of components retrieved from your sandbox using metadata. An excerpt below from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_about_force.com_projects.htm).

> Each project is connected to a Salesforce organization, known as its home organization, and contains a set of files which correspond to metadata components stored in the home organization’s database.

So as long as you know your server instance, just provide it in the section, and you should be good to go. And [here's](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002889&type=1) how you can always find your instance information.